# how to find exponential weighted moving average using dataframe.ewma?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Previously I used the following to calculate the ewma

```
dataset['26ema'] = pd.ewma(dataset['price'], span=26)
```

But, in the latest version of pandas pd.ewma has been removed. How to calculate using the new method dataframe.ewma?

```
dataset['26ema'] = dataset['price'].ewma(span=26)
```

This is giving an error 'AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ewma'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`Series.ewm`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ewm.html):

```
dataset['price'].ewm(span=26)
```

See [GH11603](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/11603) for the relevant PR and mapping of the old API to new ones.

---

**Minimal Code Example**

```
s = pd.Series(range(5))
s.ewm(span=3).mean()

0    0.000000
1    0.666667
2    1.428571
3    2.266667
4    3.161290
dtype: float64
```